# Is it possible to feed dynamic shape matrix in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have data set with unstatic shape like `(batch_size, None, None, None, 92)`

```
for x in x_data:
    print(x.shape)
(4, 4, 8, 92)
(3, 3, 7, 92)
(4, 4, 8, 92)
(3, 3, 7, 92)
(4, 4, 8, 92)
(4, 4, 7, 92)
(3, 3, 7, 92)
(4, 4, 8, 92)
(4, 4, 8, 92)
(3, 3, 8, 92)
```

But when I try to feed this **x_data** to my **X place holder** I faced error

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, None, None, 92])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    c, _ = sess.run([cost, optimizer], feed_dict={X: x_data, Y: y_data})
```

This error may caused from unstatic shape of input data.

Error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/bsjun/Documents/GitHub/CCpyNN/CCpyNN/Inception_v.2.py", line 274, in <module>
    c, hy, _ = sess.run([cost, logit_layer, optimizer], feed_dict={X: batch_x[i], Y: batch_y[i], keep_prob: 0.8})
  File "C:\Users\bsjun\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tf_normal\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 929, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\bsjun\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tf_normal\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1121, in _run
    np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
  File "C:\Users\bsjun\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tf_normal\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 501, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Is it impossible to feed dynamic shape matrix ?

Here is a summary of my code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

shapes = [(4, 4, 8, 92), (3, 3, 7, 92), (4, 4, 8, 92), (3, 3, 7, 92)]
x_data = []
for s in shapes:
    x = np.zeros(shape=s)
    print(x.shape)
    x_data.append(x)

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, None, None, 92])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(X, feed_dict={X: x_data})
```

Answer (score 2):

It won't work for the data which you provide, but there are some options how to deal with that.

**Why it doesn't work**

The line

```
 x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, None, 92])
```

means that the shape of the input array is not known beforehand. But it must be an object which could be converted numpy array. As your input data is a sequence of numpy arrays of different shapes, it won't be converted.

**How to deal with that**

**1. Provide separate input for your model.** You could, probably, modify the code of your model, providing it two inputs:

- Input data with the "maximum" shape. That means, that any array from your sequence would fit into this shape;
- Actual shapes of the input arrays.

Such approach is used, for example, in the [tf.nn.dynamic_rnn()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn), where one of the parameters is the actual data, and another is `sequence_length` - the length of each sequence.

**2. Vary shape of data from batch to batch.**  Another option would be to feed arrays of different shapes on each batch. So, for example, you group `batch_size` arrays of shape (4, 4, 8, 92) into one batch and feed it into the model. Then you take `batch_size` arrays of shape (3, 3, 8, 92) and do one more pass and so on. So, the shape can vary in the dataset, but it should be constant in the single batch.

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually, I was trying to do exactly same with second option. I'll do both and compare which one is better.

Comment: Probably the second option is the easiest one. Will it work or not depends on your data. Please, share your experience regarding comparison. And don't be shy to accept the correct answer at stackoverflow ;)